# Bootstrap collapsed navbar button hidden when clicked?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've searched for any possible reasons for my issue but have come up empty. I'm using Bootstrap and I have a collapsed navbar that, when clicked, generates a line underneath the button but doesn't present the menu. Then, clicking on it the second time, it flashes the menu but it then quickly disappears automatically and won't stay visible.

I'm sure its a simple fix but I'm new so its not that simple for me ;) Seeking some guidance. Thanks.

I'm not sure how much code and what code to post here so I'll put the link as well: [eci.surge.sh](http://eci.surge.sh)

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="scroll-top"><img src="assets/images/ecsi_logo2.jpg" style="max-height: 50px; padding-top: 7px;" class="center-block" alt="ECI Logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-6 inline-block">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-transparent">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="about"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="construction"><strong>Construction</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="environmental"><strong>Environmental</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="vacuum"><strong>Vacuum Services</strong></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="coatings"><strong>Coatings</strong></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#nav { 
height:70px;
width: 100%;
position:fixed;
padding-top: 2px;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#ac0008;
z-index:9999;
display: none; 
}

.navbar {
background-color: transparent;
background: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
float: none;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 26px;
padding: 9px 10px 11px;
text-decoration: none;
color:  #ddd;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the collapsed class to your nav-toggle button:

```
<button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
```

Comment: Thanks, Travis. Interestingly making that change reversed the order: now it produces the line on the second click and flashes the menu on the first.

Comment: The navbar needs to be hidden on load, with it appearing on scroll. Removing that display property dismisses that. However, it turns out I had more navbar css buried way down in the file and I found the culprit. Your bootply led me to look deeper. Thanks. I didn't end up needing to add the "collapsed" class to the button and I could keep the display: none property - I just removed some additional navbar styling from a media query that for some stupid reason I had in there: '    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    } '